# defining custom constant or using pre-defined constants in zend framework

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework

I would like to be able use custom constants in my zend framework like this

```
$upload->setDestination(FILE_UPLOAD_DESTINATION); //set destination upload dir
```

where `FILE_UPLOAD_DESTINATION` would be a path predefined in some other file. So that later when i need to change this path, rather than hunting down line by line, i can simply change a particular constant in one central file.

i know i can be done easily using `include` in normal PHP scripts but i was hoping if there is similar functionality built into ZF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the path in your application.ini and in your Bootsrap.php you can make a constant for this path. For example:

in application.ini:

```
myvars.fileuploaddir = APPLICATION_PATH "/../public/images"
```

and in Bootstrap.php you can do:

```
protected function _initMakeFileUploadConsant() {

    $myVars = $this->getOption('myvars');

    $imgDir = realpath($myVars['fileuploaddir']);

    defined('FILE_UPLOAD_DESTINATION') || define('FILE_UPLOAD_DESTINATION', $imgDir);

}
```

Comment: but i still need to declare them twice; first in application.ini and then in Bootstrap.php. I was expecting more like a declare once and use it anywhere approach because there can be a handful of them.

Comment: @anp. So could just declare them in boostrap.php only or in index.php.

Comment: i think i'll declare them in index.php. btw, is it necessary to have 'defined('FILE_UPLOAD_DESTINATION') ||' in the beginning of the define statements ?

Comment: @anp. I would recommend putting under defined('APPLICATION_PATH') and defined('APPLICATION_PATH'). This way you can use these constants for defining FILE_UPLOAD_DESTINATION.

Comment: @Marcin can i save all the variables i want to use inside a php file in `config` dir and do a `require_once` in `index.php` ?

Comment: @anp. I don't see a reason why not.